# How do I return a string from a javacc method?

Tags: java, string, parsing, compiler-construction, javacc

I have this method in javacc to parse a url (e.g. /books/id/1). How do I make this method return the whole url string?

```
void path() :
{}
{
  (< SLASH > ( < IDENTIFIER >))+
}
```

I have tried to create a Token t to absorve all the tokens but it's not working.

```
void path() :
{Token t = new Token();}
{
  t = ((< SLASH > ( < IDENTIFIER >))+)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the string using the following code:

```
String path() :
{String path = "";
Token slash = null;
Token id = null;}
{
  (slash = < SLASH > ( id = < IDENTIFIER >)
  {
    path += slash.toString() + id.toString();
  })+
  {
    return path;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just capture the first and last token and then create the string by traversing the resulting linked list.  See Q5.2 in the FAQ at http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ

Comment: I liked that! Thanks for the FAQ link, it has a lot of helpful content!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best (and most accurate way) is to define a token, and then use it in methods:

```
TOKEN:
{
    < PATH: (<SLASH> (<IDENTIFIER >))+ >
}
```

And then you'll be able to consume it in methods like this:

```
String path():
{ Token t; }
{
    t = <PATH>
    {
        return t.image;
    }
}
```